# RViz does not respect transparency (alpha) for a simple URDF component (e.g. cylinder)

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to make a part of my URDF model semi transparent since the part is a clear 12" acrylic plate.  So I tried making the plate a flat cylinder with a light grey color and alpha set to 0.1 as shown below.  However, the plate looks solid grey in RViz--the same as if I had set alpha to 1.0.  I can make the whole robot more or less transparent by changing the alpha property for the Robot Model display.  However, I want just the plate to be transparent.  Below is a test URDF file that illustrates the problem.  I am trying this using the latest Electric debian packages under Ubuntu 10.04.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- XML namespaces -->
<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" 
       name="test_urdf">
       
        <link name="base_link">
            <visual>    
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="0.005" radius="0.15" />
                </geometry>
                <material name="clear_color">
                    <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 0.1"/>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10858/rviz-does-not-respect-transparency-(alpha)-for-a-simple-urdf-component-(e.g.-cylinder)/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-08-26**:
+1: I have seen the same problem in diamondback on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you report this problem on the bug tracking of the visualization stack? You find a link at the bottom of the wiki page http://www.ros.org/wiki/visualization

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-01**:
Done!  The ticket can be found here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5145